# Flexbox: How to wrap items inside flexbox when bottom of the page is reached?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on custom startpage. My goal is to have a few columns next to each other inside a flexbox. The columns themselves are also flexboxes and are filled with circles that will later become links.

What I am trying to achieve is to limit the maximum height of the startpage to the visible screen area and to have the circles inside the columns wrap to the top of the column when the column reaches the bottom of the page.

This works when I set a fixed height for the columns (for example 900 px). However, when I set a relative height, the items do not wrap but overflow over the bottom of the page and the scrollbar appears.

How can I adjust my code, so that the content is restricted to the visible screen area?

I'm fairly new to html, this is my first real project so my code may seem a bit weird in some places.

This is my html markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="row1" class="fixedflex">This is the header</div>

        <div id="row2" class="flexflex">
            <div class="tilebox">
                <div class="tilecolumn">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>                    

                </div>

                <div class="tilecolumn">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="tilecolumn">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <footer id="row3" class="fixedflex">Footer</footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

And this is part of the css-stylesheet

```
.wrapper {
/*
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 1px;
*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

}

.fixedflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    width: 100%;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.flexflex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;

    flex: 2;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: yellow;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.tilebox {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width:5px;

    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;

    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tilecolumn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    max-height: 100%;

    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;

    flex-wrap: wrap;

    flex-basis: 20%;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-shrink: 2;

    margin: 20px;

}

.tile {
    display: flex;

    margin: 10px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    color: var(--text_color);
    text-decoration: none;

    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    justify-content: center;

    border-radius: 50%;

    background: var(--light_background);
}
```

I'm also using a normalize.css, but I don't think there's anything in there that could cause my issue.

Comment: Is the idea that each tile will contain one of the circle links?

Comment: Each tile would be one circle. But Aymen's answer already seems to fix my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i started by fixing the height of the `fixedflex` to 20px , so the heighth of the `flexflex` should be 100vh - the heighth of the two `fixedflex` and the border so it will be : `height: calc(100vh - 72px);` : stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfpckr

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="row1" class="fixedflex">This is the header</div>

        <div id="row2" class="flexflex">
            <div class="tilebox">
                <div class="tilecolumn">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                    <div class="tile"></div>                    

                </div>

                <div class="tilecolumn">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="tilecolumn">
                    <div class="tile"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <footer id="row3" class="fixedflex">Footer</footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
/*
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 1px;
*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: column;

}

.fixedflex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 20px;

    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.flexflex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: calc(100vh - 72px);
    flex: 1;

    border-style: solid;
    border-color: yellow;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.tilebox {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width:5px;

    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;

    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tilecolumn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    max-height: 100%;

    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;

    flex-wrap: wrap;

    flex-basis: 20%;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-shrink: 2;

    margin: 20px;

}

.tile {
    display: flex;

    margin: 10px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    color: var(--text_color);
    text-decoration: none;

    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    justify-content: center;

    border-radius: 50%;

    background: var(--light_background);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes my problem!

Comment: anytime @Jonas ^^